# search parameter in lightning combobox to search data-table not working

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using 2 combobox to serch Region and workplace for selected record ID Values are populated into combobox correctly. But when I pass the workplace and region parameters datatable shows no data. my code are below

APEX class

```
public with sharing class ListScopeAssessments {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Scope_Set_Assignment__c> getScopeAssessments(string recId, string region, string workplace){
        if(region==null)
        { region='';}
        if(workplace==null)
        { workplace='';}
        
        string regionName = '%'+region+'%';
        string workplaceName = '%'+workplace+'%';
        system.debug('===Serch Region ==='+ regionName);
        
        List<Scope_Set_Assignment__c> scopeList = new List<Scope_Set_Assignment__c>();
        for(Scope_Set_Assignment__c sList:
         [Select 
            Id, 
            Name, 
            Region__c, 
            Account__c, 
            Contact_Name__c,
            Contact__c, 
            Assignment_Status__c, 
            Awarded__c, 
            FSM__c
        FROM Scope_Set_Assignment__c 
        WHERE Scope_Set__c=:recId 
        AND Region__c like :regionName 
        AND Account__c like :workplaceName
        WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED 
        ])
        {
            scopeList.add(sList);
        }
        return scopeList;
    }

    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)                
    public static List<Scope_Set_Assignment__c> getRegionPicklistValues(string recId) {
        List<Scope_Set_Assignment__c> regionList = new List<Scope_Set_Assignment__c>(
                [SELECT
                        Region__c
                FROM Scope_Set_Assignment__c 
                WHERE Scope_Set__c=:recId]);
        Map<String, Scope_Set_Assignment__c> uniqueRegionMap = new Map<String, Scope_Set_Assignment__c>();

                for (Scope_Set_Assignment__c scopesetassmt : regionList) {
                    uniqueRegionMap.put(scopesetassmt.Region__c, scopesetassmt);
                }
                return uniqueRegionMap.values();        
    } 

    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)                
    public static List<Scope_Set_Assignment__c> getAccountPicklistValues(string recId) {
        List<Scope_Set_Assignment__c> accountList = new List<Scope_Set_Assignment__c>(
                [SELECT
                    Account__c
                FROM Scope_Set_Assignment__c 
                WHERE Scope_Set__c=:recId]);
        Map<String, Scope_Set_Assignment__c> uniqueAccountMap = new Map<String, Scope_Set_Assignment__c>();

                for (Scope_Set_Assignment__c scopesetassmt : accountList) {
                    uniqueAccountMap.put(scopesetassmt.Account__c, scopesetassmt);
                }
                return uniqueAccountMap.values();        
    } 
}
```

JS File

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire,track } from 'lwc';
import getScopeAssessments from '@salesforce/apex/ListScopeAssessments.getScopeAssessments';
import getRegionPicklistValues from '@salesforce/apex/ListScopeAssessments.getRegionPicklistValues';
import getAccountPicklistValues from '@salesforce/apex/ListScopeAssessments.getAccountPicklistValues';
//var i=0;
export default class ListScopeAssessments extends LightningElement {
   
    picklist;
    //picklistR;
    
    columns = [
        {label: 'Scope Set Assignment', 
            fieldName: 'ScopeName', 
            type: 'url',
            typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Name' }, target: '_blank'},
            sortable: true, 
            cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' }
        },
        {label: 'Contact', 
            fieldName: 'ContactName', 
            type: 'url',
            typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Contact_Name__c' }, target: '_blank'},
            sortable: true, 
            cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' }
        },
        {label: 'Region', 
            fieldName: 'Region__c', 
            type:'string', 
            sortable: true
        },
        {label: 'Account', 
            fieldName: 'Account__c', 
            type: 'string', 
            sortable: true
        },
        {label: 'Status', 
            fieldName: 'Assignment_Status__c', 
            type: 'string', 
            sortable: true
        },
        {label: 'Awarded', 
            fieldName: 'Awarded__c', 
            type:'date', 
            sortable: true
        },
        {label: 'FSM', 
            fieldName: 'FSM__c', 
            type: 'boolean', 
            sortable: true
        }        
    ];

// Search input details
workplacePicklist = [{label:'All', value: ''}];
regionPicklist = [{label:'All', value: ''}];

    @track sortBy;
    @track sortDirection;
    scopeAssmt = [];
    @api recordId;
    @api regionKey;
    @api workplaceKey;
    @wire(getScopeAssessments, { recId: '$recordId', workplace: '$workplaceKey', region: '$regionKey' })     
  
    scopeAssessments({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            let tempConList = []; 
              data.forEach((record) => {
                let tempConRec = Object.assign({}, record);  
                tempConRec.ScopeName = '/' + tempConRec.Id;
                tempConRec.ContactName = '/' + tempConRec.Contact__c;
                tempConList.push(tempConRec);            
            });
            this.scopeAssmt = tempConList;
            this.error = undefined;
            console.table(this.scopeAssmt);
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }

    doSorting(event) {
        this.sortBy = event.detail.fieldName;
        this.sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
        this.sortData(this.sortBy, this.sortDirection);
    }
    
    sortData(fieldname, direction) {
        let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.scopeAssmt));
        // Return the value stored in the field
        let keyValue = (a) => {
            return a[fieldname];
        };
        // cheking reverse direction
        let isReverse = direction === 'asc' ? 1: -1;
        // sorting data
        parseData.sort((x, y) => {
            x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : ''; // handling null values
            y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';
            // sorting values based on direction
            return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
        });
        this.scopeAssmt = parseData;
    }    

    handleChange(event){
        // eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-api-reassignments
        this.workplace=event.currentTarget.value;
        console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
    } 
    //Getting picklist values
    @wire(getAccountPicklistValues, {recId: '$recordId'})
    mapPicklistAccount({data,error}) {
        if(data) {
            console.log('data');
            console.log(data);
            let workplaces = [];
            // eslint-disable-next-line guard-for-in
            for (let key in data) {
                const options = {
                    label: data[key].Account__c,
                    value: data[key].Account__c
                }
                workplaces.push(options)
            }
            console.log(workplaces)
            this.workplacePicklist = [... this.workplacePicklist, ...new Set(workplaces.sort())];
            
            console.log('picklist')
            console.log(this.workplacePicklist)
        }
        if(error) {
            console.log('picklist');
            console.log(error);
        }
    } 
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-dupe-class-members
    @wire(getRegionPicklistValues, {recId: '$recordId'})
    mapPicklistRegion({data,error}) {
        if(data) {
            console.log('data');
            console.log(data);
            let regions = [];
            // eslint-disable-next-line guard-for-in
            for (let key in data) {
                const options = {
                    label: data[key].Region__c,
                    value: data[key].Region__c
                }
                regions.push(options)
            }
            console.log(regions)
            this.regionPicklist = [... this.regionPicklist, ...new Set(regions.sort())];

            console.log('picklistR')
            console.log(this.regionPicklist)
        }
        if(error) {
            console.log('picklistR');
            console.log(error);
        }
    } 
 }
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout-item size="12" medium-device-size="6">
        <template if:true={workplacePicklist}>
            <lightning-combobox style="width:40%;"
                data-id='Account__c'
                data-type='String'
                data-operator='EQUALS'
                placeholder="Choose Workplace"
                name='Workplace'
                label='Workplace'
                options={workplacePicklist}
                onchange={handleChange} 
                class="slds-var-m-horizontal_x-small">
               
            </lightning-combobox>
        </template>
    </lightning-layout-item>

    <lightning-layout-item size="12" medium-device-size="6">
        <template if:true={regionPicklist}>
            <lightning-combobox style="width:40%;"
                data-id='Region__c'
                data-type='String'
                data-operator='EQUALS'
                placeholder="Choose Region"
                name='Region'
                label='Region'
                options={regionPicklist}
                class="slds-var-m-horizontal_x-small">
            </lightning-combobox>
        </template>
    </lightning-layout-item>

<lightning-layout-item size="12" medium-device-size="6">   
        <lightning-datatable 
            key-field="id"
            class="slds-max-medium-table_stacked-horizontal"
            columns={columns} 
            hide-checkbox-column
            show-row-number-column
            data={scopeAssmt} 
            sorted-by={sortBy}
            sorted-direction={sortDirection}
            onsort={doSorting}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </lightning-layout-item>
</template>
```

Comment: Try removing `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED ` then you'll know if it's the permissions and field level security settings of the user's profile that are causing this. You can put back again after you have got it all working.

Comment: Thanks fixed by initializing parameters to NULL